# How to set a default folder when opening Finder

Tags: macos, finder, defaults

I am new on MacOS, would like to set a default folder to open Finder, instead of Recent items folder.

I tried:

`defaults write com.apple.finder NewWindowTargetPath -string "file:///Users/path/to/folder"`

But didn't worked...

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finder → Preferences (⌘,) → General and set ‘New Finder windows show’, either pick from the list or choose Other and specify a custom path.

You don't *need* to set the key manually using Terminal, but you should be able to with this:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder NewWindowTargetPath -string "file://localhost/Users/path/to/folder/"
```

Note the trailing slash at the end and the use of localhost, both of which are how Finder writes the key itself.

Comment: Monterey (might be true of Big Sur too) doesn't need the `localhost`. This is how I set mine to ~/Downloads `defaults write com.apple.finder NewWindowTargetPath -string "file://$HOME/Downloads/"`

Answer (score 9):

A couple of quick things that may help if you are looking to set Desktop or Documents as the default for Finder...

Set Desktop as Default:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder NewWindowTarget -string "PfDe"
```

Set Documents as Default:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder NewWindowTarget -string "PfDo"
```

Comment: And the home folder is `"PfHm"`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer, confirm to work on latest MacOS 13.4.1

Comment: Still works on macOS 14.0